# Print all sheets in workbook except for 3 specific sheets

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I want to print all the sheets in the workbook I am working in except for Three specific sheets called "Front Page", "Data" and "Logs". I've tried with an "and"- and an "or"-statement and wrapped parenthesis around and nothing worked.

Here's the code:

```
Sub printsheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If  ws.Name <> "Front Page" And _
            ws.Name <> "Data" And _
            ws.Name <> "Logs" Then
            ws.PrintOut
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: This should work. Did you double-check the sheet names? Is there any whitespace? Try with `Trim(ws.Name) <> ...`.

Comment: I see no Error's on your code, it should work.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I get the following error message: "Run-time error '1004' Method 'PrintOut' og object'_Worksheet' failed. @stribizhev, just tried with the Trim function. It don't work. The only sheets that were printed were "Master" and "Logs" - 2 of 3 sheets that I did not want to be printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have hidden worksheets in your workbook.

Before printing them, you need to unhide them, or check if the worksheet is hidden. Either manually, or (especially if your sheets were hidden programmatically with `xlSheetVeryHidden`):

```
ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible ' ADD THIS LINE TO UNHIDE A SHEET
ws.PrintOut
```

Or

```
If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
   ws.PrintOut
End if
```

Try something like this **if you do not want to print out hidden worksheets**:

```
Sub printsheets()
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  If ws.Visible = True Then
   If ws.Name <> "Front Page" And _
    ws.Name <> "Data" And _
    ws.Name <> "Logs" Then
       With ws.PageSetup
        .PrintArea = "b2:g26" ' USE YOUR PRINTAREA
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
       End With
       ws.PrintOut
   End If
  End If
 Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh, didn't know that hidden sheet would cause problems. I do not want the hidden sheet to be printed, so I was thinking something in line with: Sub printsheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws.Visible In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Front Page" And _
            ws.Name <> "Data" And _
            ws.Name <> "Logs" Then
            ws.PrintOut
        End If
    Next ws


End Sub But it's not working.

Comment: Just added another and statement (I'm guessing your code does the same trick and looks better): Sub printsheets()
Sub printsheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Front Page" And _
            ws.Name <> "Data" And _
            ws.Name <> "Logs" And _
            ws.Visible = True Then
            ws.PrintOut
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub.

Comment: The next step is to fit each sheet into one page. I was thinking in the lines of:     With ActiveWorkbook.ws.PageSetup
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlPortrait
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
    End With. I'm in doubt where in the existing code I should insert it.

Comment: The tick right below the down arrow on the left :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use one list with the sheets that you don't want to print

```
Sub printsheets()
    Dim dontPrint As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set dontPrint = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    dontPrint.Add "Front Page", 1
    dontPrint.Add "Data", 2
    dontPrint.Add "Logs", 3


    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
     If dontPrint.Exists(ws.Name) Then
     Else
        ws.PrintOut
     End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Fabrizio, I'm not sure I understand the fourth line. Btw, I just tried the code. Got the same error as before :/